# Group together similar entries in the query in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, while-loop

I want to group together the Airports that share the same 'city' column.
Right now they're all listed side by side which is good, but I want to add an extra option tag for each city that has two airports.

For example right now my code shows:

**New York - JFK**

**New York - La Guardia**

**Los Angeles - LAX**

But I want it to show:

**New York - All**

**New York - JFK**

**New York - La Guardia**

**Los Angeles - LAX**

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance

```
$getairportsfrom=mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * FROM details WHERE type='Airport' ORDER BY city");

                   while($rowfrom = mysqli_fetch_array($getairportsfrom)) {
               echo "<option value='".$rowfrom['title']."'>" . $rowfrom['city'] . " - " . $rowfrom['title'] . "</option>";
                   }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is your query:

```
SELECT city, title
FROM details
WHERE type = 'Airport'
ORDER BY city;
```

You can get what you want with this query:

```
select city, title
from ((select city, 'All' as title, 1 as ordering
       from details
       group by city
       having count(*) > 1
      ) union all
      (select city, title, 2 as ordering
       from details
      )
     ) d
order by city, ordering;
```

SQL isn't really designed for this type of manipulations for presentation.  However, it is possible to do this.

Comment: I ended up doing it myself, with a similar code using GROUP BY before I see your answer. Your code is much cleaner though and I might implement it instead. Thanks very much!